# Vue 3 nested transition not working, no error

Tags: vue.js, css-animations, vuejs3, vue-transitions

I have this Vue3 Root component, showing a list of groups where each group can have n entries.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import EntryItem from '../components/EntryItem.vue';
let groups = [
{
   name:'Foo'
   entries:[
   {
    name:'Bar'
   },
   {
    name:'FooBar'
   }
  ]
}
];
let deleteGroup = group => {
 groups.filter(item => item.name != group)
};
</script>
<template>
  <ul>
    <transition-group name="groups" tag="div" enter-active-class="bounceInDown" leave-active-class="slideOutRight">
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in groups"
        class="my-2 px-4 py-2 rounded shadow"
        :key="`root_${item.name}`">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
          <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="ml-2" @click.prevent="deleteGroup(item.name)">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ml-4" v-if="item.entries.length > 0">
          <transition-group name="entries" tag="div" enter-active-class="bounceInDown" leave-active-class="slideOutRight">
            <EntryItem v-for="entry in item.entries" :key="`entry_${entry.name}`" :entry="entry" />
          </transition-group>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </ul>
</template>
<style scoped>
@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0) scaleY(3);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0) scaleY(0.9);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) scaleY(0.95);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0) scaleY(0.985);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.bounceInDown {
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
@keyframes slideOutRight {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideOutRight {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: slideOutRight;
}
</style>
```

EntryItem Component renders the entries for each group.
This should also slide out to the right, after deleting an entry.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
let deleteEntry = name => {
 entry.filter(item => item.name != name) }
};
const props = defineProps(['entry']);
</script>
<template>
  <li>
    <div class="flex justify-between">
      <div>
      {{ entry.name }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteEntry(entry.name)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
<style scoped>
@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0) scaleY(3);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0) scaleY(0.9);
  }

  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) scaleY(0.95);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0) scaleY(0.985);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.bounceInDown {
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
@keyframes slideOutRight {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideOutRight {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: slideOutRight;
}
</style>
```

If I delete a Group it slides out to the right.
However, deleting an Entry doesn't animate. It just get's removed.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you add all the code in codesanbox and paste it here?

Comment: Had to use StackBlitz because I'm using vite
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-pxv4rp

Deleting entries sometimes animates, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `ul` that just removes the entire  `transition-group`
so when you delete the last element, you don't see the transition  because `<ul class="ml-4" v-if="item.entries.length > 0">`   removes the entire group.

You could just delete the `v-if="item.entries.length > 0"` part and have it transtion-group render 0 items.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <transition-group
      appear
      name="groups"
      tag="div"
      enter-active-class="bounceInDown"
      leave-active-class="slideOutRight"
    >
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in groups"
        class="my-2 px-4 py-2 rounded shadow"
        :key="`root_${item.name}`"
      >
        <div class="flex justify-between">
          <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="ml-2" @click.prevent="deleteGroup(item.id)">
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ml-4">
          <transition-group
            name="entries"
            tag="div"
            enter-active-class="bounceInDown"
            leave-active-class="slideOutRight"
          >
            <EntryItem
              v-for="entry in item.entries"
              :key="`entry_${entry.name}`"
              :entry="entry"
            />
          </transition-group>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </ul>
</template>
```